# Python type hints: set kwagrs to TypedDict instead of dict in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I'm trying to declare a specific structure annotation for kwargs:

```
class MyType(TypedDict):
    request: PydanticPayload
    args: Dict[str, Any]


def handle_request(self, **kwargs: MyType) -> PydanticResponse:
```

But Pycharm expects that kwargs will be `Dict[str, MyType]` instead of `MyType`.

Is there any way to make Pycharm identify kwargs as `MyType`?

Comment: You can't control what ends up in kwargs. If you only want to accept specific arguments, write them as regular keyword-only arguments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a way to support kwargs' specific type,

So I made sure I send only the specific arguments:

On the class that calls `handle_request` I did:

```
        self.function = handle_request # (HAPPENS DYNAMICALLY)



        args = flask_request.view_args
        query = flask_request.args
        flask_request_parameters = dict(request=request,
                                        args=args,
                                        query=query)

        function_params = list(inspect.signature(self.function).parameters)
        expected = {key: flask_request_parameters[key] for key in function_params}

        result = self.function(**function_params)
```